# Determine if Text file is empty or is displaying incorrect information

Tags: windows, text

I saved a .txt file in 2017 with some names and numbers however when I have gone back to open the file now, the file only contains empty spaces - the file has not been modified since the creation date so I am wondering whether I can do anything to retrieve whatever data may be hidden within it. As much as I would like to know what could have happened, I am more interested in retrieving the data itself.

Comment: What's the media where the file is on? If you opened the file and you see only spaces... this doesn't look promising. If you want, you can put it here so I can run some tools in it. https://gofile.io/?t=uploadFiles

Comment: What do you mean by media? It's on the Laptop HDD
EDIT: text file is uploaded here: https://gofile.io/?c=nIYfWh

Comment: I was talking about the type of HDD, like SSD or regular HDD. But anyway, that file of your is actually blank, it doesn't show anything inside. I tried to quickly  see if got encrypted inside, or getting packaged or something like that, but I cannot see anything. Encoding is fine too, it doesn't even look corrupted, but only has spaces inside (0x20) chars only.